# Why my program using switch always go to default

Tags: javascript

My program always outpout test which should not happen. Its like the program is skipping the case to go to default right away. I don't understand why it does that. I've spent 30 mins to find a solution but I can't understand why it does that.

Thanks for helping me !

```
var ani;
let ans;
let prix;
var total;
var arm1;
var arm2;
let nombrearmure;
nombrearmure = 0;
ani = prompt("Entrez votre type d'animal : ");
switch (ani.toLowerCase) {
case 'c' :
    ans = prompt('Voulez vous acheter une épée pour 100$ ? : ');
    if (ans.toLowerCase() === 'o'){
        prix = 100;
        nombrearmure = 1;
    } else {
        if (ans.toLowerCase() === 'n') {
            console.log('Épée refusé');
        } else {
            console.log('Réponse non valide');
            
        }
    
    }
    ans = prompt('Voulez vous acheter une corne de licorne pour 500 $ ? : ');
    if(ans.toLowerCase() === 'o'){
        prix = prix+500;
        nombrearmure = nombrearmure + 2;
    } else {
        if (ans.toLowerCase() === 'n'){
            console.log('Corne de licorne refusé');
        } else {
            console.log('Réponse invalide');
            
        }
    }

    break;
case 'l' :
    ans = prompt('Voulez vous acheter un casque(100-200$) : ');
    if (ans.toLowerCase() === 'o'){
        ans = parseInt(prompt('Appuyez sur 1 pour un casque noir (100$) ou 2 pour un casque multicolore (200$) : '));
        switch(ans){
            case 1 :
                prix = 100;
                nombrearmure = 1;
                break;
            case 2 :
                prix = 200
                nombrearmure = 2;
                break;
            default :
            console.log('Réponse invalide')
            return 1;
        }
    } else {
        if(ans.toLowerCase === 'n'){
            console.log('Casque refusé');
        } else {
            
        }
    }
default:
    console.log('test');
}
```

Comment: remove the return keyword it's "illegal",also lowerCase needs to be called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing `ani.toLowerCase`. It should be `ani.toLowerCase()`. Also remove the return 1.

Comment: Thanks ! What should I put instead of return to stop the program at this place ?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call the lowerCase function, invoke it.
Also, remove the return statement,

Now if you try to enter 'l' or 'c' letter it will work

```js
var ani;
let ans;
let prix;
var total;
var arm1;
var arm2;
let nombrearmure;
nombrearmure = 0;
ani = prompt("Entrez votre type d'animal : ");
switch (ani.toLowerCase()) {
  case 'c':
    ans = prompt('Voulez vous acheter une épée pour 100$ ? : ');
    if (ans.toLowerCase() === 'o') {
      prix = 100;
      nombrearmure = 1;
    } else {
      if (ans.toLowerCase() === 'n') {
        console.log('Épée refusé');
      } else {
        console.log('Réponse non valide');

      }

    }
    ans = prompt('Voulez vous acheter une corne de licorne pour 500 $ ? : ');
    if (ans.toLowerCase() === 'o') {
      prix = prix + 500;
      nombrearmure = nombrearmure + 2;
    } else {
      if (ans.toLowerCase() === 'n') {
        console.log('Corne de licorne refusé');
      } else {
        console.log('Réponse invalide');

      }
    }

    break;
  case 'l':
    ans = prompt('Voulez vous acheter un casque(100-200$) : ');
    if (ans.toLowerCase() === 'o') {
      ans = parseInt(prompt('Appuyez sur 1 pour un casque noir (100$) ou 2 pour un casque multicolore (200$) : '));
      switch (ans) {
        case 1:
          prix = 100;
          nombrearmure = 1;
          break;
        case 2:
          prix = 200
          nombrearmure = 2;
          break;
        default:
          console.log('Réponse invalide')

      }
    } else {
      if (ans.toLowerCase === 'n') {
        console.log('Casque refusé');
      } else {

      }
    }
  default:
    console.log('test');
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! What should I put instead of return to stop the program at this place ?

Comment: you can put break instead like for the other cases